# Sort table rows by ASC, DESC (different type of content per column)

Tags: html, jquery

I have this function:

```
function sortTable(index) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, array = [];
  table = $("table");
  switching = true;
  
  while (switching) {
    
    switching = false;
    rows = table.find("tbody tr:not(.table-extra-hidden)");

    
    for (i = 0; i < (rows.length); i++) {
      
      shouldSwitch = false;
      
      x = rows.eq(i).find("td").eq(index);
      y = rows.eq(i + 1).find("td").eq(index);
      
      if(sortOrder == "desc" && x.find('.primary-info').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,'') < y.find('.primary-info').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,''))
      {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      
      if(sortOrder == "asc")
      {
        rows.eq(i).insertBefore(rows.eq(i-1));
      }
      else
      {
        rows.eq(i).insertAfter(table.find("tr:not(.table-extra-hidden)").last());
      }
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The click event:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).attr("href") == "#")
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    if($(this).closest("th").length)
    {
      $("th").not($(this).closest("th")).find("a").removeClass("is-sorted sort-desc sort-asc")
      if($(this).hasClass("is-sorted"))
      {
        if($(this).hasClass("sort-desc"))
        {
          $(this).removeClass("sort-desc").addClass("sort-asc");
        }
        else
        {
          $(this).removeClass("sort-asc").addClass("sort-desc");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $(this).addClass("is-sorted sort-desc");
      }

      //get table column index.
      var index = $(this).closest("th").index();

      var switching, table, rows, x, y, shouldSwitch;

      if($(this).hasClass("sort-desc"))
      {
        sortOrder = "desc";
      }
      else if($(this).hasClass("sort-asc"))
      {
        sortOrder = "asc";
      }
      sortTable(index);
    }
}
```

It's used to sort this table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="#">Date</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Amount</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Trade</a></th>
        <th class="no-pointer"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-paired="1" tabindex="0">
        <td>
          <b>Bitcoin Buy</b>
          <br />
          <span class="primary-info">Jan 21, 2022</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="primary-info">$1,800.00</b>
          <br>
          <span>0.00035678 BTC at $34,557.80</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="primary-info">Trade</span>
        </td>
        <td class="expandable-trigger">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-sm" data-icon-name="chevron-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-extra-hidden" data-paired="1">
        <td>
          <b>Status</b>
          <br>
          <span>Filled</span>
          <br><br>
          <b>Filed</b>
          <br>
          <span>Jan 1, 2022, 6:31 AM EST</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>Paid With</b>
          <br>
          <span>20.00000000 GUSD</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-paired="2" tabindex="0">
        <td>
          <b class="buy-option">Dogecoin Buy</b>
          <br />
          <span class="primary-info">Jan 20, 2022</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="primary-info">$50.00</b>
          <br>
          <span class="converstion-option">0.00035678 BTC at $34,557.80</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="primary-info">Trade</span>
        </td>
        <td class="expandable-trigger">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-sm" data-icon-name="chevron-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-paired="3" tabindex="0">
        <td>
          <b class="buy-option">Bitcoin Trade</b>
          <br />
          <span class="primary-info">Jan 21, 2022</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="primary-info">$1,200.00</b>
          <br>
          <span class="converstion-option">0.00035678 BTC at $34,557.80</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="primary-info">ACH Deposit</span>
        </td>
        <td class="expandable-trigger">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-sm" data-icon-name="chevron-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-paired="4" tabindex="0">
        <td>
          <b class="buy-option">Bitcoin Interest Paid</b>
          <br />
          <span class="primary-info">Dec 15, 2021</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="primary-info">$1,900.00</b>
          <br>
          <span class="converstion-option">0.00035678 BTC at $34,557.80</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="primary-info">Interest Payment</span>
        </td>
        <td class="expandable-trigger">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-sm" data-icon-name="chevron-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-paired="5" tabindex="0">
        <td>
          <b class="buy-option">Deposit from Chase</b>
          <br />
          <span class="primary-info">Dec 1, 2021</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="primary-info">$800.00</b>
          <br>
          <span class="converstion-option">0.00035678 BTC at $34,557.80</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="primary-info">Trade</span>
        </td>
        <td class="expandable-trigger">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon icon-sm" data-icon-name="chevron-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

There are two things:

Firstly, a column when sorted is finding the class name "primary-info" to sort from that data point (vs everything) and secondly each column has different data points that can be sorted by. This doesn't seem to be working and just infinitely looping instead sorting and stopping. What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you call `sortTable`?

Comment: It's within a click event for a header. I can post.

Comment: Yes, make it reproducible. Also, is it intended that you implemented a sort algorithm? Why not use the native `sort` method?

Comment: There is a native sort method? I thought that was only for arrays?

Comment: Yes, I mean: put the data in a temporary array, sort, and populate the DOM with it.

Comment: Interesting, that could be a way, but not sure where to start

Comment: What is this `table-extra-hidden` hidden about? Where should such rows go? To the top?

Comment: It's an expandable row that is hidden by default.

Comment: OK, but what should be the effect of sorting be on them? Should they go to the top, to the bottom, stay with some particular other row? Is it actually relevant to your question?

Comment: It could be. The intent is to sort all the non `table-extra-hidden` rows to the right order, then have those ones follow their parent rows (associate each data-paired attribute with one another) - I was going to do it after I got help with sorting the top level ones because that's the more important.

Comment: OK, so if I answer, I will not pay attention to those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
      if(sortOrder == "desc" && x.find('.primary-info').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,'') < y.find('.primary-info').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g,''))
      {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
```

This means that whatever the `if` condition evaluates to, it will set `shouldSwitch` to true and exit the inner loop. As a consequence the outer loop will keep iterating.

You should just remove the `else` block.

NB: it is more common practice to use the `Array#sort` method for sorting a table. First put rows in an array, sort it, and then populate the table again in that order.